# Telerik Kendo UI Grid Vue messages for pagination do not seem to be working

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to change the pagination display message from the default which is this:
[image: sample screen shot]

`'{0} - {1} of {2} items'`

ex: "1 - 10 of 1000 items'

to this:
`'TEST {0:#,###} - {1:#,###} of {2:#,###} items TEST'`

ex: "TEST 1 - 10 of 1,000 items TEST"

it does not seem to be working for me.

```
{
  ...
  pageable: {
    messages: {
      display: "TEST {0:#,##} - {1:#,##} of {2:#,##} items TEST"
    }
  }
}
```

Documentation here:

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/pageable.messages#pageablemessagesdisplay

Sample Code here (that does not seem to be working):
Feel free to play around to see if you can get it to work.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/g9ehqb-p6ig9m?file=src%2Fmain.vue

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation for [vue](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/grid/api/GridPagerSettings/) doesn't mention the `messages` property so I guess it's not supported.

Comment: @JoeGlover actually, that link was helpful, it put me on the path to https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/grid/globalization/

grid.pagerInfo "{0} - {1} of {2} items"

Looks like I might be able to do it with localization. Now I just need to figure out how to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, in the end, you need to use the LocalizationProvider and IntlProvider

```
<LocalizationProvider language="en-EN">
  <IntlProvider locale="en">
    <Grid
       ...
    </Grid>
  </IntlProvider>
</LocalizationProvider>

import { IntlProvider, LocalizationProvider, loadMessages } from '@progress/kendo-vue-intl';

loadMessages(
  {
    grid: {
      pagerInfo: '{0:#,###} - {1:#,###} of {2:#,###} ítems',
    },
  },
  'en-EN'
);
```

That did it.

This link helped me along: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/grid/globalization/